# AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store: Lambda function hangs

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a simple lambda function that reads values from parameter store. Frustrated that it doesn't work granted an IAM role with "Administrator Access". Wonder why it would gets timeout even after 30 seconds!

```cs
public class Function
{
    private static IConfigurationRoot? Configuration;
    public string FunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        context.Logger.LogInformation("Before Service Handler");
        IServiceCollection services = ConfigureServices("NYSECalendar",context);
        ServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var logger = provider.GetService<ILogger<Function>>();
        context.Logger.LogInformation("After Service Handler");
        if (logger != null)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("After service Handler");
        }        
        ServiceHandler.CloseLogger();
        return "Hello";
    }
    private static IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(string applicationName, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.Logger;
        logger.LogInformation("Creating SeriveCollection");
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        logger.LogInformation("Creating IConfigurationBuilder");
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.AddSystemsManager(@"/MicroStockServices/");
        logger.LogInformation("Building");

//Never comes out of builder.Build <=======
        Configuration = builder.Build();

//Build Complete is not in my cloud watch log!

        logger.LogInformation("Build Complete");
        logger.LogInformation($"{Configuration.Providers.Count()} providers");
        return services;
    }
}
```

Of course, the above code works in Visual Studio with no issues.

Did anyone encounter this and if yes how did you fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow your EC2, Lambda, or whatever you're using, access to your Parameter Store via an IAM role.

The policy you need to attach to the role would be like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had quite the same issue, maybe this is helping.

`SystemsManager` needs access to the web, otherwise it will freeze waiting to connect (without any log unfortunately).
Therefore Lambda should be connected to an internal subnet, there should be a NAT gateway in place and a routing from external subnet and the internal subnet.

Comment: Spent all day trying to figure out why it was hanging with no logs and eventual timeout... The VPC config was wrong!